# Choose proper grounding when using multiple LDO, buck, buck-boost and invering regulators

Tags: grounding, ground-loop, common-mode

I'm a little stumped by how to avoid ground loops. I need to connect to a mostly analog external component that requires VCC_12V, VCC_5V, VCC_3V3, VCC_N7V (\$-7.0V\$) and GND. I assume the external component returns all supplies back to GND.

However, in order to supply these voltages, I have designed regulators providing quiet analog voltages using LDOs following buck, buck-boost and inverting switching regulators. Due to the different voltages, the ground outputs are necessarily different for each of the voltages.

Below, I've indicated why there would be a loop, if I connect the returns of the supplies.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPtjr1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The sensible thing would be to connect the external components ground to the ground of my power source (as indicated), but I fear that there will be too much noise, since now the noisy traces are included in the voltage levels.

Comment: GND in a circuit diagram is just a point we (more or less) arbitrarily chose to reference all voltages to and consider absolute and stable; in a real PCB however GND is some complex shape of copper with currents flowing in all kinds of paths, causing all points of it to have a different voltage. Figure out where thes currents are and where the voltages are lifted above the ideal GND and avoide those to reference any voltages against, that is half of avoiding such issues.

Comment: Yes, the trace resistance basically represents the voltage drop on the PCB due to fast switching in the converters. After that is the LDO and then two outputs (VCC and GND). But I can't connect the 4 GNDs together, to hook up the external component.

Comment: I don't really agree with PlasmaHH. Ground is a place you should deliberately choose to avoid ground loops and other shenanigans. It's only really ever 0 where you measure it to be. In a star grounding paradigm, you measure the center of the star.

Comment: There is no 'true ground' every single point on this planet has some kind of 'common mode' voltage generated from the return current flowing through whatever material it flows through to return to its source. Unless you are using a superconductor, the potential of whatever ground you are measuring is slightly higher than the local earth ground (earth isn't even zero, it varies by location). Engineers should minimize the problem and make it negligible for their application.

Comment: One approach worth mentioning (for protecting signals from ground loops) is balanced lines. Unbalanced signaling is susceptible to ground loops because the signal is referenced to ground on both ends, and the two lines have different impedances so any stray currents that are equal cause unequal voltages.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, if I could redesign the external load, I would make sure it had separate returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching regulators create high pulsing ground currents, so their grounds should be connected close to the supply and not shared with other circuits. If the load is remote then its ground may develop a potential difference due to its own current draw, but it won't suffer interference from the switching regulator.

3 terminal linear regulators only put a small constant current into their Ground (or Adjust) terminal. Since the Ground terminal is used to sense output voltage, it should be wired as close as possible to the load ground. With this connection the regulator's output voltage will be more stable at the load, and not suffer from noise in the ground wire between the load and power supply.

So your layout should look like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Ghg8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ground loops are a problem for a few reasons. Loops, like you mentioned are one reason, its a great way to turn the design into an antenna. This is bad if you are trying to pass an FCC regulation or if your design is susceptible to EMI. Minimize the loop area as much as you can. If EMI still becomes a problem, try increasing the increasing the inductance of the loop on the non ground side with ferrites to block high frequency noise.

A bigger problem can be common mode noise.

If you look at this figure from Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering by Henry W. Ott, you can see why this would be a problem. The current from the 'upstream' regulators is going to bump up the voltage on the downstream regulators.

[image: From Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering].

A bigger question is, will this effect the design? It depends on the currents and the impedance. It also depends on what other circuits you have, and if they are sensitive to grounding changes. If you are trying to measure millivolts to microvolts then you might have trouble. If your circuit is purely digital, then some common mode noise might not be a problem. Use equation 3-4 (come up with a similar equation and diagram) either measure the ground noise or it can be found in some datasheets.

If the ground currents are not varying, then the voltage common to both of the regulators will be constant. If it is constant, it may not be a problem. (this would be unlikely, I know of few circuits that draw constant loads these days)

Minimizing the impedance of the wire between the regulators will help by reducing the voltage from the resistance of the wire. Changing the wire size to a larger size would help, reducing the wire length would help.

Swapping the order of the devices in series can also change the current flowing through each section of wire, which might also help.

If these options fail, then you may have to switch to a muti-point ground or a combination of the two.